# Как убрать из меню загрузки опции проверки памяти на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Как убрать из меню загрузки опции проверки памяти на Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно выполнить команды:

```
$ sudo chmod -x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
$ sudo update-grub
```

и опции исчезнут.

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно так. В файле /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ находим строку

```
 if test -e /boot/memtest86+.bin ; then
```

и в ней портим имя файла, типа

```
 if test -e /boot/memtest86+.bin__ ; then
```

Далее

```
sudo update-grub
```

У меня получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Просто отредактируйте /boot/grub/menu.lst

В этом текстовом файле должна быть строчка title memtest86+

Удаляем ее и все строчки после нее до следующий строки title

Comment: И при следующем обновлении ядра все вернется.
Ясно же сказано в начале файла: не править вручную!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu(kubuntu,lubuntu,xubuntu) во время установки устанавливает кучу ненужных пакетов и один из них - это memtest+. Чтобы его не было в меню grub, нужно просто удалить пакет memtest+